# How to access SCOTUS opinion announcements from the bench

Tags: us-supreme-court

I guess my query is in the title.

I read that the Supreme Court of the United States [would resume annunciation of its opinions](https://www.scotusblog.com/2022/12/court-will-resume-opinion-announcements-from-the-bench-but-wont-provide-live-audio/), but I have not, for the life of me, been able to find announcements from previous terms. I believe they're on the website of the National Archives, but I still can't locate them.

Could anyone here help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oyez.org hosts these when they become available. E.g.: https://www.oyez.org/cases/2017/16-402

However, the Court does not make these available until long after the opinion announcement (generally, at the beginning of the following term).